# How to pass parameter value to stage build in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline created which takes the parameter value from the user. I want to trigger a jenkin job using this parameter.
How can I pass the parameter value to the build's parameter.
Here is my code:

```
pipeline {
 agent any
 parameters {
  string(name: 'SYSTEM', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter array. Example:SYS-123')

  string(name: 'EMail', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter email id')

 }
 stages {
  stage('Example') {
   steps {
    echo "Hello ${params.SYSTEM}"
    echo "Hello ${params.EMail}"
   }
  }
  stage('core-rest-api-sanity') {
   steps {
    build job: 'xyz', parameters: [string(name: 'E-Mail', value: ${params.EMail}), string(name: 'SYSTEM', value: ${params.SYSTEM})]
   }
  }
 }
}
```

In the above code, I am taking email and system details from the user. Then I want to trigger my job "xyz" which would require these parameter.

Comment: Your pipeline looks fine. What’s the problem here? If your downstream job is unable to access the parameters, use `"${params.EMail}"` (notice the double quotes) or just `params.EMail` while passing it to the downstream job.

Comment: Thanks @DibakarAditya. The double quotes worked.

Comment: instead of the quotes, you can use params.EMail directly

Answer (score 1):

```
    pipeline {
 agent any
 parameters {
  string(name: 'SYSTEM', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter array. Example:SYS-123')

  string(name: 'EMail', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter email id')

 }
 stages {
  stage('Example') {
   steps {
    echo "Hello ${params.SYSTEM}"
    echo "Hello ${params.EMail}"
   }
  }
  stage('core-rest-api-sanity') {
   steps {
      build job: 'xyz', parameters: [string(name: 'E-Mail', value: params.EMail), 
        string(name: 'SYSTEM', value: params.SYSTEM)]
     }
    }
   }
  }
```